# MKAnnonationView transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, mkmapview

i'm trying to create a MKAnnonationView, but when i tap the annonations they appear with a transparent background. When i press the segmentControllr which shows tableView instead of MKMapView then its white until i tap the annonation again then it become transperent again.

[image]

## viewdidLoad

```
    pointMapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.width, self.tableView.frame.height))
    pointMapView?.showsUserLocation = true
```

## add MKAnnonations

```
func setGeoPoint(geoPoint:PFGeoPoint, titleString:NSString, imageFile:PFFile, theId:NSString, descString:NSString, dateString:NSString) {

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude) as CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var pinView:AnnonationClass = AnnonationClass()

    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            let theImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
            pinView.itemImage = theImage
            pinView.setCoordinate(coordinate)
            pinView.title = titleString
            pinView.subtitle = dateString

            self.pointMapView!.addAnnotation(pinView)
        }
    }
```

## viewForAnnonation

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: AnnonationClass!) -> MKAnnotationView! {



    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.pinColor = .Purple



        var rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
        //MapPointAnnotation *point = (MapPointAnnotation*)pinView.annotation;
        //rightButton.venue = point.venue;
        rightButton.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)

        rightButton.addTarget(self, action: "rightButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as UIView


        var leftImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
        leftImage.image = annotation.itemImage
        pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftImage

    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```